# Emacs 25 png background transparency issue and sluggish init

Tags: start-up

I have just upgraded to Emacs 25 (windows 32-bit version on Windows 10), and found out that there are still quite a few things to smooth out.
One includes potentially the PNG background not being transparent.
On Emacs 25:
[image: Emacs 25]
On Emacs 24:
[image: Emacs 24]
Or is it just me due to my settings? By the way they're using the same .emacs init file.

Oh, also my Emacs 24 starts in about 5 seconds, while the new Emacs 25 takes about 8 seconds.

Hope there can be some tips from members here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Emacs loads different logo images depending upon certain criteria (e.g., support for viewing certain image types).  I am uncertain if the issue is the image being viewed transparently versus opaque.  The image may have even changed between Emacs versions.  To see what I am referring to, type `M-x find-function RET fancy-splash-image-file RET`  You can also evaluate that function and see what value it returns.  Is it a png?

Comment: Here is the function:
``(defun fancy-splash-image-file ()
  (cond ((stringp fancy-splash-image) fancy-splash-image)
 ((display-color-p)
  (cond ((<= (display-planes) 8)
  (if (image-type-available-p 'xpm)
      "splash.xpm"
    "splash.pbm"))
        ((or (image-type-available-p 'svg)
      (image-type-available-p 'imagemagick))
  "splash.svg")
        ((image-type-available-p 'png)
  "splash.png")
        ((image-type-available-p 'xpm)
  "splash.xpm")
        (t "splash.pbm")))
 (t "splash.pbm")))``

Comment: And I found splash files of these four types: PBM, PNG, SVG, XPM in the [C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Emacs 25.1\share\emacs\25.1\etc\images] folder.

My ELisp is at infancy. Does it say that it prefers XPM, but at the end it sets to PBM?

Comment: The function is identical on the startup.el of 24.5 and the 25.1. And there are also 4 splash screen files with the same names in both image folders.

Answer (score 1):

I 'solved' this mystery by replacement the four splash screen image files of 25.1 by those in version 24.5
The missing transparency of the logo at the 'About' screen is due to the newer version's splash screen files.

Comment: Re slowness, the first binary release of 25.1 for Windows was compiled without optimization, https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2016-11/msg00255.html